# div is not updating using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is the code when i enter the room capacity (say Ex: 20 ) in the respective div it gives the details of different branches presented in that 20 capacity. but when i edit any of the previous inputs for strength the changes are not reflecting in the desired divs

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">                    </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        var x=2;
         var rem=0;   


        $('#add').click(function(){
           var maxfields=50;

           if(x<=maxfields)
           {      
              $('#more').append('<br><div id="p1">Room '+x+': <input type="text" name="room[]" maxlength="10"> Strength '+x+': <input type="text" name="stre[]" class="room"  min="1" max="36"><div id="div'+x+'">'+x+'</div></div></br>');
             x++;
           }
           else
           {
              alert('you reached the max limit');
           }

          });

       });
      </script>
    <style>
      input
      {
        height:30px;  
      }
       #add
      {
         background-color:#ffffff;
         font-family:arial;
         border-radius:5px;
         border-collapse:collapse;
         border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
         height:30px; 
       }
       td
       {
         height:30px;
         width:125px;
         text-align:center;
         font-weight:bold;
       }

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         include('connect.php');
         $year=$_POST['yr'];
         $sem=$_POST['sm'];
         $date=$_POST['dt'];
         $course=$_POST['crs'];
         $session=$_POST['ss'];
         $reg=$_POST['reg'];

       session_start();
      $_SESSION['yr']=$year;
      $_SESSION['sm']=$sem;
      $_SESSION['dt']=$date;
      $_SESSION['crs']=$course;
      $_SESSION['ss']=$session;
      $_SESSION['rg']=$reg;


      $sql="select * from seating where year='$year' and sem='$sem' and course='$course' and session='$session' and reg='$reg' and date='$date'";
      $query=mysql_query($sql);
      $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
   ?>

    <center><table border='1'>
      <tr><td>Total Strength</td><td>Remaining</td></tr>
     <tr><td><?php echo"$count";?></td><td><div id="rem"></div></td></tr>
    </table></center>


    <br></br>
    <div class='disp'>
    <button id="add">Add Room</button><br></br>
      <form method="post" action="rooms_post.php" target="_parent">
     <div id="p1">Room 1: <input type="text" name="room[]" maxlength="10"> Strength 1: <input type="text" name="stre[]" class="room" min="1" max="36">      <div id="div1">This is div1</div></div><br>
     <div id="more"></div></div><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn-success" disabled="disabled" />
      </form>
    </div>

   <script>
        var rem=0;
        var tot=<?php echo $count; ?>;
        $("#rem").html(tot).val()

        $(document).on("change",".room",function(){

               var sum = 0;
               var k=0;

              $(".room").each(function(){

                   k=k+1;       
                   sum += +$(this).val();
                   var cap=$(this).val();
                   var start=sum-cap+1;     
                   var end=sum;
                  alert(k); 
                  $.ajax({
                       type:'POST',
                       url:'disp.php',
                       data:'start_id='+start+'&end_id='+end,
                       success:function(gethtml)
                     {
                         $('#div'+k+').html(gethtml);                   
                     }
                 });

            });

               if(sum%4==0)
               {

                  rem=tot-sum;

                      $("#rem").html(rem).val()

                        if(rem==0)
                        {
                          $("#add").attr("disabled", true);
                          $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", false);    
                          $("#rem").css("background-color", "#ffa5a5");  
                        }
                        else if(rem<0)
                        {
                           alert('Capacity exceeded the remaining');
                           $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true);    
                           $("#add").attr("disabled", true);    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#add").attr("disabled", false);   
                            $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true);
                            $("#rem").css("background-color", "#a9fc97");    
                        }
                     }
                    else
                    {

                      alert('Capacity must be multiple of 4');
                      $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true); 
                      $("#add").attr("disabled", true); 
                    }  
                   });

                  </script>

          </body>
        </html>
```

and the another program disp.php is given here

```
      <html>
       <head>

       </head>

    <?php

        include('connect.php');

        $start=$_POST['start_id'];
        $end=$_POST['end_id'];

        $sql="select branch,count(*) as ct from seating where id between $start and $end group by branch";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
           $br=$row['branch'];
           $ct=$row['ct'];

          echo"$br -> $ct,";         
        }


       ?>
      </html>
```

Comment: you have multiple versions of `var rem;` - One is global and one is local to a document ready, you probably want to fix that.  I would put all your js together so that you don't get errors like this and it makes it more maintainable

Comment: If you move `$('#more').append.....` etc to the else statement, does it append the new data to `#more`? This will tell you if it's the fault of the if statement or not.

Comment: You could also `$('#more').append('test text');` to see if simplifying it works either.

Comment: problem is with the divs i have created during add more. the task is i will enter the room no. and capacity. with respect to that it is to give what are the different courses presented in that room within the capacity and should tell the strength. this task is written in disp.php. when i enter the capacity it is showing correctly. but when i edit the previous entered capacity the result is not showing accordingly.

Comment: anybody clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

change your change function to

$(document).on("change",".room",function(){

```
           var sum = 0;
           var k=0;

          $(".room").each(function(){

               k=k+1;       
               sum += +$(this).val();
               var cap=$(this).val();
               var start=sum-cap+1;     
               var end=sum;
              alert(k); 
              $.ajax({
                   type:'POST',
                   url:'disp.php',
                   data:'start_id='+start+'&end_id='+end,
                   success:function(gethtml)
                 {
                     $('#div'+k).html(gethtml);                   
                 }
             });

        });
```